# I need that a resizable (jQuery ui) div in a TH don't go smaller that TD width or make TD overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, jquery-ui-resizable

I have this headers on a table with a div inside:

```
<TH><DIV class="resize">Name of Column</DIV></TH>
<TH><DIV class="resize">Name of Column2</DIV></TH>

$(".resize").resizable();
```

When the user resize the div I need it to stop when the TD cannot get any smaller, or make the TD text overflowable (new word :D) under the next TD.

I tried by given all TD a class call hideOverflow and put the overflow property hidden, but the TD always stop shrinking at the biggest word it contains. So I need the div inside the TH to stop shrinking at the same width that the TD or make the TD continue shrinking with an overflow hidden.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this by adding DIVs to the TDs and make them "overflow:hidden" as well